# InnoDB: Cannot create ./ib_logfile101

Tags: mysql, linux

I want to change the datadir of the mysql, so I copy the ./mysql/ to a new dir.
This is the command i used:

```
cp ./mysql /home/data/
```

But failed when i start the mysql service.paste the log and the error:

```
  2018-12-14T08:59:23.456895Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
  2018-12-14T08:59:23.460926Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
  2018-12-14T08:59:23.473245Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
  2018-12-14T08:59:23.473273Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
  2018-12-14T08:59:23.473289Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot create ./ib_logfile101
  2018-12-14T08:59:23.473300Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
  2018-12-14T08:59:24.073902Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
  2018-12-14T08:59:24.073942Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
  2018-12-14T08:59:24.073952Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
  2018-12-14T08:59:24.073960Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: sorry ,i didn't know how to make this to be more beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

It's right there in your error messages:

```
2018-12-14T08:59:23.473245Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
2018-12-14T08:59:23.473273Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
```

Try

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql #or whatever your new directory is
```

Comment: yes ,you are right,this problem has solved.thank  you.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Feel free to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To move the storage of MySQL on linux, you have to do 3 things:

1. Shut down the service `sudo systemctl stop mysql`
2. Move the current storage to a new place (the process you are describing in your question)
3. Change variable `datadir` in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` from `datadir=/var/lib/mysql` to `datadir=/home/data/`

I believe you forgot to do the 3rd step.

Comment: Don't forget to start the service after these changes of course :) `sudo systemctl start mysql`

Comment: yes,i forgot the step 1. could you teach me how to solve this question.please.

Comment: Do you mean closing this question as solved in stackoverflow or how to solve step one from my answer in your linux system?

Comment: For stopping the mysql service, just run the command provided. (It will require superuser password.).
For closing the question on Stackoverflow: There is a gray tick on the top left for each answer to this question. Just check the tick for the answer that helped you solve the problem. It will turn green. You can also upvote the answer. That's it.